# Removing ASP.NET_SessionId from an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-4.5

I am changing session state in:

```
<sessionState cookieName="myCookieName" />
```

It changed correctly, but one issue I am facing is default the "ASP.NET_SessionId" is also showing.

I didn't understand what I am going wrong. How can I fix this?

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieName="foo" />
</system.web>
```

I need only to show a cookie named `foo`. I don't want to show "ASP.NET_SessionId".

Comment: Where is it showing? Where you don't want to show?

Comment: first of all thank you for the reply.
Its showing in the web browser cookie and i don't want to show the "ASP.NET_SessionId" in the web browser cookie

Issue in detail :

I would like to change ASP.NET session cookie name "ASP.NET_Sessionid" to some other name. I specified <sessionState cookieName="MyCookieName" />. When I use fiddler and browser to view response header, I can see "MyCookieName" with random generated number under cookie section, however, ASP.NET_SessionId also exist there.

Comment: Clear browser cache memory whenever change cookie name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's just a cache issue. Try to delete the cookie in the browser.

Then log in again, and see if it appears again...

Comment: tried and tired. many times cleared the brrowser cookies and cache. is there any thing like restart the server. making use of that.

Comment: The only think I can think is maybe you have another site in the same domain that still uses the original cookie...

Comment: @ Rui caramalho, you said it right that was the problem

Comment: Thanks Its Worked ,it was cache-issue